# wget, logging the output and the response

Tags: bash, shell-script, logs, wget, output

I calling an url using wget. This url gives me a response, its a Message id. I want to write the logs to a log file, with the message id as well. Also the log should be appended each time. I trying to do it in my shell script.

Is it possible to do this? If so how can i do it.

Comment: Did you already try using `wget`'s `--append-output=logfile` (`-a logfile`) option? It looks like it is precisely what you would need.

Comment: @Emeric I have tried that it works fine for writing the output to the file. I also want the response to be written to the same file after the output. I need help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wget -O - $url --append-output=logfile >> logfile
```

Specifying `-` as filename for `-O` writes the output to stdout.

My shell does not hate using `logfile` for both append operations. It might work for you as well.

Comment: It works like a charm, Thanks, but is there a way to have the response after the output instead of the with the output.

Comment: You can try using `-nv,  --no-verbose` option. It reduces the `-a` part to a single line, but that single line can only be displayed *after* the requested contents have been retrieved (and therefore written to the logfile) since it also records whether the retrieval was successful.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around

```
wget --no-check-certificate -O contnt -a logfile $url
cat contnt >> logfile 
rm contnt
```

is there any other better way of doing this which doesnt include reading from the file and deleting the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
wget - $url --server-response --append-output=logfile
```